# Batch - Read and sum values from different TXT files

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd

I have a folder with some txt.files like this example

file1.txt:

```
'NumberOfEntries'|'TotalAmount1'|'TotalAmount2'
'10'|'150250.02'|'327535.49'
```

File2.txt:

```
'NumberOfEntries'|'TotalAmount1'|'TotalAmount2'
'15'|'327551.09'|'18761432.56'
```

File3.txt:

```
'NumberOfEntries'|'TotalAmount1'|'TotalAmount2'
'20'|'100000.44'|'220030.90'
```

and so on..

What I need is to sum it up, keeping the header and sum the values of the second row, getting something like this:

FileALL.txt:

```
'NumberOfEntries'|'TotalAmount1'|'TotalAmount2'
'45'|'577801.55'|'19308998.95'
```

And I need this to be generic, meaning for other types of headers, for files with more or less columns, etc ..

So far I managed to get the header from the first file but for the rest I'm kind of stuck:

```
del "%CD%\%year%\ALL\fileALL.txt"   
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%year%\folder\file_01.txt) do (
    echo %%a >> "%CD%\%year%\ALL\fileALL.txt"
    goto _ExitForLoop
    )
:_ExitForLoop

for %%F in (%year%\folder\*.txt) do (
  set /a total1=0
  set /a total2=0
  set /a total3=0
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=|" %%a in ("%%F") do set /a total1+=%%a
  for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=|" %%b in ("%%F") do set /a total2+=%%b
  for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=|" %%c in ("%%F") do set /a total3+=%%c
  echo %total1%|%total2%|%total3% > "%CD%\%year%\ALL\fileALL.txt"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Questions resembling "Here are my requirements.  Now write it for me." aren't well-received around here.  Better hurry and edit or delete your question before the flood of down votes starts.  Show some code you've written, the errors resulting from your misadventures, something to demonstrate you've put in some effort to solve this problem on your own before asking us.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @rojo, I'm not a regular user of stackoverflow, it was not on purpose, of course I wrote some code, edited right now with some of my code trying to solve the problem. 
Can you give some help?

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read the header and get the number of columns from it
for %%F in (*.txt) do set /P "header=" < %%F & goto ExitForLoop
:ExitForLoop
set "cols=0"
set "line=%header%"
:nextCol
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%a in ("%line%") do (
      set /A cols+=1
      set "line=%%b"
   )
if defined line goto nextCol

rem Initialize the array of totals
for /L %%i in (1,1,%cols%) do set "total[%%i]=0"

for %%F in (*.txt) do (
   for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%L in ("%%F") do (
      set "line=%%L"
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%cols%) do (
         for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%a in ("!line!") do (
            set "col=%%a"
            set "col=!col:'=!"
            set /A "total[%%i]+=!col:.=!"
            set "line=%%b"
         )
      )
   )
)

rem Show totals
< NUL (
   echo !header!
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%cols%) do (
      if %%i equ 1 (
         set /P "='!total[%%i]!'"
      ) else (
         set /P "=|'!total[%%i]:~0,-2!.!total[%%i]:~-2!'"
      )
   )
   echo/
) > fileALL.txt
```

Output:

```
'NumberOfEntries'|'TotalAmount1'|'TotalAmount2'
'45'|'577801.55'|'19308998.95'
```

**Notes:**

- This program fail if any file have less number of data columns.
- The result will be wrong if any data column from 2 on don't have *precisely* two decimal places.

Comment: Bah, you beat my edit and undelete.  +1.  `:P`  I like how you scrape the header and number of columns, too.

Answer (score 1):

Batch does not have native floating point support, and it is often awkward to parse text reliably.

You could use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to efficiently solve this problem with a bit of user supplied JScript. JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The solution below works with the exact format listed in the question. It assumes all rows have the correct number of columns, and each field has a value. It also assumes that the last row of each file is terminated by `\r\n` or `\n`.

The code is a long one liner. I use `^` line continuation to make the code easier to read.

```
type "%year%\folder\*.txt" 2>nul|jrepl ^
  "^'(\d+)'\|'(\d*\.?\d*)'\|'(\d*\.?\d*)'$ ^.+"^
  "a+=parseInt($2);b+=parseFloat($3);c+=parseFloat($4);false h=$0;false"^
  /jbeg "var h,a=0,b=0,c=0; function r(n){return Math.round(n*100)/100}"^
  /jend "output.WriteLine(''+h+'\r\n\''+a+'\'|\''+r(b)+'\'|\''+r(c)+'\'')"^
  /t " " /jmatch /o "%year%\ALL\fileALL.txt"
```

The `type` command combines each of the files into a single stream of data, which is the reason why each file must end with a `\n`. The output is piped into JREPL, which does the rest of the work.

The `/jmatch` option treats the replacement strings as JScript expressions that are evaluated, and only outputs matching replacement values.

The `/t " "` option treats both the search and replace strings as a set of space delimited strings. The first search string is replaced by the first replacement string, the second search string is replaced by the second replacement string, etc.

The `/o` option specifies the output file.

The `/jbeg` option defines and initializes variables to hold the header record as well as the three aggregate columns values. It also defines a function to round a floating point number to two decimal places. Rounding is needed because floating point numbers do not represent numbers exactly.

The first search string (captured as `$1`) matches the data rows, and captures each field value in `$2`, `$3`, and `$4`. The corresponding replace JScript string parses the values and adds them to the aggregate values. It returns `false` to disable any normal output.

The second search string (captured as `$5`) matches any entire line that was not matched by the first. If the the files are formatted properly, then this will always be a header record. The replacement JScript string simply stores the matched string (`$0` always represents the entire matched string) in the header variable, and returns `false` to disable output. The last header found "wins", but I assume they are all the same.

Finally, the `/jend` option is finalization code that writes out the header row and the final aggregate value row, with proper rounding.